# My hangman game finishes before the whole word is guessed

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a hangman game in visual basic. This is my code.

I think the problem is located under the private sub labelcheck(), but I've tried to remove the AndAlso, etc, but nothing seems to work. I am new to visual basic, so I have very limited understanding of how to debug these kinds of problem. Thank you.[This is  picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNDgS.png)

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Public n As Integer
    Public a As String

    Private Sub Button30_Click(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button30.Click
        For Each button As Button In GroupBox1.Controls
            button.Enabled = True
        Next
        If File.Exists("C:\dictionary.txt") Then
            Dim words() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\dictionary.txt")
            Dim r As New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
            n = r.Next(0, 80368)
            Dim amount As Integer = words(n).Count()
            Label9.Text = "Letters:" & " " & amount
            Dim letters() As Char = words(n)
            Dim idxnum As Integer = 0

            For Each labelitm As Label In Me.GroupBox2.Controls
                If idxnum = amount - 1 Then
                    labelitm.Text = letters(idxnum)
                Else
                    labelitm.Text = ""
                End If
                idxnum = idxnum + 1
            Next

            For Each labelitm As Label In GroupBox2.Controls
                If labelitm.Text = "" Then
                Else
                    labelitm.Visible = False
                End If
            Next
        Else

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub labelcheck()
        For Each labelitm As Label In GroupBox2.Controls
            If a = labelitm.Text Then
                labelitm.Visible = True
                If Label1.Visible AndAlso Label2.Visible AndAlso Label3.Visible AndAlso Label4.Visible AndAlso Label5.Visible AndAlso Label6.Visible AndAlso Label7.Visible AndAlso Label8.Visible = True Then
                    MessageBox.Show("You won!")
                    Button30.PerformClick()
                End If
            Else

            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click, Button10.Click, Button11.Click, Button12.Click, Button13.Click, Button14.Click, Button15.Click, Button16.Click, Button17.Click, Button18.Click, Button19.Click, Button20.Click, Button21.Click, Button22.Click, Button23.Click, Button24.Click, Button25.Click, Button26.Click, Button27.Click, Button28.Click, Button29.Click

        Select Case DirectCast(sender, Button).Name
            Case "Button1"
                Button1.Enabled = False
                a = "a"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button2"
                Button2.Enabled = False
                a = "b"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button3"
                Button3.Enabled = False
                a = "c"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button4"
                Button4.Enabled = False
                a = "d"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button5"
                Button5.Enabled = False
                a = "e"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button6"
                Button6.Enabled = False
                a = "f"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button7"
                Button7.Enabled = False
                a = "g"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button8"
                Button8.Enabled = False
                a = "h"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button9"
                Button9.Enabled = False
                a = "i"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button10"
                Button10.Enabled = False
                a = "j"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button11"
                Button11.Enabled = False
                a = "k"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button12"
                Button12.Enabled = False
                a = "l"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button13"
                Button13.Enabled = False
                a = "m"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button14"
                Button14.Enabled = False
                a = "n"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button15"
                Button15.Enabled = False
                a = "o"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button16"
                Button16.Enabled = False
                a = "p"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button17"
                Button17.Enabled = False
                a = "q"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button18"
                Button18.Enabled = False
                a = "r"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button19"
                Button19.Enabled = False
                a = "s"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button20"
                Button20.Enabled = False
                a = "t"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button21"
                Button21.Enabled = False
                a = "u"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button22"
                Button22.Enabled = False
                a = "v"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button23"
                Button23.Enabled = False
                a = "w"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button24"
                Button24.Enabled = False
                a = "x"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button25"
                Button25.Enabled = False
                a = "y"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button26"
                Button26.Enabled = False
                a = "z"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button27"
                Button27.Enabled = False
                a = "ø"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button28"
                Button28.Enabled = False
                a = "ø"
                labelcheck()
            Case "Button29"
                Button29.Enabled = False
                a = "å  "
                labelcheck()
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: It would appear that all the labels are visible, so you did win.  Visible is not the same as Enabled

Comment: The labels are set to be invisible when I click the "new game" button, or have i done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `labelcheck()`, you are iterating over `Control`s, using a `Label` object. You should use the `Controls.OfType(Of Label)` to return only `Label`s

```vb
For Each labelitm As Label In GroupBox2.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    If a = labelitm.Text Then
        labelitm.Enabled = True
        If Label1.Enabled AndAlso ... Then
            MessageBox.Show("You won!")
            Button30.PerformClick()
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I would also simplify your massive button click handler

```
Private Sub ButtonClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click,
    Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click,
    Button8.Click, Button9.Click, Button10.Click, Button11.Click,
    Button12.Click, Button13.Click, Button14.Click, Button15.Click,
    Button16.Click, Button17.Click, Button18.Click, Button19.Click,
    Button20.Click, Button21.Click, Button22.Click, Button23.Click,
    Button24.Click, Button25.Click, Button26.Click, Button27.Click,
    Button28.Click, Button29.Click

    Dim myButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim buttonIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(myButton.Name.Replace("Button", ""))

    Select Case buttonIndex
        Case 1 To 26
            myButton.Enabled = False
            ' See http://www.asciitable.com/
            a = Chr(buttonIndex + 96).ToString()
            labelCheck()
        Case 27, 28
            myButton.Enabled = False
            a = "ø"
            labelCheck()
        Case 29
            myButton.Enabled = False
            a = "å  "
            labelCheck()
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I still get the message "You won!" when I pick the right letter and are not able to guess the whole word. I added the .OfType(Of Label)() to all of the other loops, but it more than 1 correct letter.

Comment: According to comments on your question, you may also want to change from `Visible` to `Enabled` in the logic in this loop. I changed it in my answer.